# What is the highest RPM achieved through a spin-stabilized rocket/spacecraft?

Tags: rockets, rotation, spin-stabilisation

The title explains it all. I know that the Star 48 kick motor rotated at 60 rpm through its burn. I'd like to know the fastest a rocket/stage has spun during a launch, as well as the highest theoretical spin rate of a rocket.

Comment: "I'd like to know the fastest a rocket/stage has spun during a launch, " A *successful* launch or do you include failures?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I'm not concerned about failures or successes, I'm just wondering the maximum spin rate before vehicle breakup for the second question (could be a rocket failure like A-003), the first question must be a success.

Comment: potentially related: [Which (if any) Vanguard satellite spun at 150 RPM? How fast did the rest spin, or at leased would have spun had they succeeded?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/58029/12102)

Comment: IIRC Explorer 1 was 750rpm